# How to use node-sass in react-static

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using `react-static` and I also want to use `sass`.

This is my `package.json`:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@reach/router": "^1.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "bulma": "^0.8.0",
    "bulma-start": "^0.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-icons": "^3.8.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.25.2",
    "react-static": "^7.2.0",
    "react-static-plugin-reach-router": "^7.2.0",
    "react-static-plugin-sass": "^7.2.2",
    "react-static-plugin-sitemap": "^7.2.0",
    "react-static-plugin-source-filesystem": "^7.2.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1"
  }
```

As I know, to use sass add `node-sass` and import SCSS file. 
But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they have a [plugin](https://github.com/react-static/react-static/tree/master/packages/react-static-plugin-sass) on SASS integration. Follow their installation and after that you can import your SASS files.

Answer (score 0):

you can use webpack for this.

```
{
    test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
             'style-loader',
             'css-loader',
             'sass-loader',
        ]
}
```

add this in your "rules" array under "module" object.